# Bootstrap element floating left goes down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following code based on Bootstrap:
http://www.bootply.com/7CrOKKpXGv

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="logo-bag">
  </div>
  <div class="store-description">
      <div class="description">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mollis mauris ac laoreet sagittis. Suspendisse ultricies tincidunt convallis. Nam in varius odio, ac ultrices turpis. Sed urna libero, mattis sit amet lacus eget, varius vulputate felis. Nullam finibus, erat sed pharetra sagittis, metus neque tincidunt enim, ut malesuada leo lorem lacinia ex. Praesent convallis dolor porta nibh luctus congue. Nunc nec diam dui. Vestibulum rhoncus orci at ligula porttitor, at varius tellus elementum. Morbi pulvinar tellus nisl, non pulvinar erat egestas a. Ut bibendum libero ex, sagittis accumsan neque vestibulum eu. Cras tincidunt mollis dolor in posuere. Vestibulum dignissim fermentum aliquet. Fusce consequat urna arcu, et varius dolor imperdiet commodo. Integer at est elit. Sed pulvinar ipsum est, eu mollis est accumsan varius. Proin iaculis nec tortor eu ullamcorper. Maecenas condimentum tincidunt quam efficitur porttitor. Ut molestie venenatis sapien, in laoreet ex interdum nec. Ut ac urna placerat, consequat augue id, porttitor mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vel congue diam. Pellentesque sit amet risus efficitur, accumsan purus sed, laoreet massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam ac ligula et dui blandit consectetur quis pellentesque turpis. Etiam venenatis vel quam eget congue. Curabitur mauris enim, pellentesque et felis ac, tempor hendrerit est. Fusce eget molestie risus. Morbi et odio ipsum. Morbi eleifend imperdiet quam, in auctor leo ultrices ac. Nam congue nulla id tempus vestibulum. Duis lacinia condimentum sollicitudin. Integer tempus nisi vel porttitor pellentesque. Sed rutrum sodales ipsum, sed suscipit sem egestas vel.Pellentesque molestie augue id dui euismod pulvinar. Quisque tristique lectus nulla, in pretium lectus pretium eu. Fusce sed mauris aliquam, dictum felis at, congue magna. Cras varius lacus nec orci molestie cursus. Proin accumsan eleifend nulla vel sollicitudin. Pellentesque ullamcorper nisi arcu, in ornare felis volutpat sit amet. Nulla feugiat consequat sem at fringilla.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  Right Sidebar
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.logo-bag {
  width: 346px;
  height: 228px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background:#000;
}
.store-description {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width:100%;
}
.description {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  background:red;
}
.description > p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: justify;
}
.col-md-4{
  background:#888;
}
.col-md-8{
  background:#CCC
}
```

I want the `div.store-description` to stay just on the right of `div.logo-bag`, regardless of browser dimensions.
The paragraph doesn't resize automatically the width, so it goes down when the browser is resized (in this case you don't need to resize the browser because I've not set a max-width to the paragraph)
How can I solve it?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: I find your question very unclear. Could you add some screenshots with what you see and what you want?

Comment: you just need to set the `width` in % to `.store-description`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly done, I've added the code to the question.

Comment: @dippas unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: @Rvervuurt I've added a performed explanation. 
Thank you for your help guys

Comment: @Victor it is not working because you set your `width` to 100%, when the maximum you can set is 60%

Comment: @dippas yes, you're right, but try to resize the browser and take a look what's happening there. The description goes down instead be resized to fit in the right side.